# Adding double click handler for Ext.ux.gauge.Gauge

Tags: extjs

The gauge widget in the ExtJS classic UX package is a great way to add a simple gauge to an application, however in my case I need to have a handler for when the gauge is double clicked.

Typically this case a listener would be added shown in [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/37rk), however the widget doesn't support that event.

Has anyone already come up with a solution for this? What would be the best approach - a custom plugin that gets added to the widget?

I see that a plugin (chartitemevents) exists for adding support for these events to charts, but I was hoping to keep the simple configuration of the UX Gauge widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the listener like below:

```
listeners: {
            dblclick: {
                fn: function () {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Click', 'Gauge has been double clicked.');
                },
                element: 'el'
            }
        }
```